Tikz-cd not showing map names
The name of the maps in the diagram do not show in my document, but it does show it in a blank one, i have remove very package that i think might have somethin to do with tikz but the error continues:

The code:
\begin{tikzcd}
\tilde{X} \arrow[rr, "\varphi"] \arrow[rd, "p"'] &   & \tilde{X} \arrow[ld, "p"] \\
                                                 & X &                          
\end{tikzcd}

how it shows:

and this are the things i import, i have it in a diferent document that the main that is a article type document.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{faktor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs} 



You also get a lot of error messages, starting with
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par

Never disregard errors. This one is caused by babel and the fact that " is a shorthand characters.
Solution: load \usetikzlibrary{babel}.
Unrelated, but you should do \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} when typesetting in Spanish; also \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is no longer needed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{faktor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\tilde{X} \arrow[rr, "\varphi"] \arrow[rd, "p"'] &   & \tilde{X} \arrow[ld, "p"] \\
                                                 & X &                          
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}



thank you so much that works perfectly

and thanks for the tip for writing in spanish, i learn many years ago from someone that propably was older than Latex sjfjshdfkjshd
